# Although there is a data row, resultset is empty

Tags: java, mysql, spring, amazon-web-services, ibatis

First of all, I'd like to explain the development environment and what I have done so far.

- The development environment consists of JAVA, Spring framework, mysql, ibatis.
- I have been trying to change the infra to AWS(Amazon) from Ncloud(NHN in Korea).
- I have a query which has to get sequence parameter.
- The query with every sequence gives result data through Workbench tool.
- After executing a program, I can see there is resultSet from log.(NHN infra)
- For some sequences, I can not see there is no resultSet. (AWS)

  < log >
  13:57:23:023 DEBUG [java.sql.PreparedStatement:27] - {pstm-132176}        Parameters: [281]
  13:57:23:023 DEBUG [java.sql.PreparedStatement:27] - {pstm-132176} Types: [java.lang.Integer]
  13:57:23:023 DEBUG [java.sql.ResultSet:27] - {rset-132177} ResultSet
  13:57:23:023 DEBUG [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager:752] - Initiating transaction commit
  13:57:23:023 DEBUG [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager:264] - Committing JDBC transaction on Connection [jdbc:mysql://***:***/***?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull, UserName=***@***, MySQL Connector Java]

  ```
  <typeAlias alias="aCellInfo" type="com.*.*.*.domain.ACellInfo" />
  <select id="selectBySeq" parameterClass="map" resultClass="aCellInfo">
  SELECT 
      a.a_seq AS aa
      ,   a.img_url AS bb
      ,   a.img_height AS cc
      ,   a.img_width AS dd
      ,   a.a_desc AS ee
      ,   a.a_nm AS ff
      ,   a.a_cnts AS gg
      ,   a.p_seq AS hh
      ,   DATE_FORMAT(a.reg_ymdt, '%Y.%m.%d') AS ii
      ,   b.b_seq AS jj
      ,   b.b_nm AS kk
      ,   c.c_cnt AS ll
      ,   a.c_type_cd mm
      ,   a.a_type_cd AS nn
  FROM
      table_a a
      LEFT OUTER JOIN table_c c ON a.a_seq = c.a_seq,
      tabble_b b
  WHERE
      b.b.seq = a.b_seq
      AND a.a_seq = #sequence#
      AND a.a_yn = 'Y'
      AND NOW() BETWEEN a.strt_ymdt AND a.end_ymdt
  ```

What I expect is there should be ResultSet because there is a data row and should be mapped to ACellInfo.
But ACellInfo instance has null in Java.

So to be short, 
- Why there is no ResultSet although there is a data row?
- Which is wrong configration?

I hope to understand this comments..

If somebody tell me what is wrong for me and solve this problem, I would appreciate to a lot!!
Have a nice day :)

Answer (score 0):

I answer it myself.
I made a mistake in spring configuration.

```
<host>
<domain>here I wrote wrong url</domain>
</host>
```